# Omit Id property in POST request to .Net Core Web Api

Tags: entity-framework, post, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have small .Net 5 Web Api project.
Code first approach is applied. MS SQL. EF Core.

The problem is - When controller receive model without `Id` - it fails with - "One or more validation errors occurred.". If controller received `Id: 0` - it is Ok, It works.

The question is - Is it possible to omit `Id` property in POST request?
I want to completely omit `Id` from request.

Model:

```
public class Playback
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required] 
        public string Video_Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Video_Duration { get; set; }
        public string Playback_User { get; set; }
        public int Playback_Duration { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddPlaybackEvent2([FromForm] Playback model)
        {
            Playback @event;
            try
            {
                @event = new Playback();
                @event.Video_Name = model.Video_Name;
                @event.Video_Duration = model.Video_Duration;
                @event.Playback_User = model.Playback_User;
                @event.Playback_Duration = model.Playback_Duration;

                _db.Playbacks.Add(@event);
                _db.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }

            return Ok(@event);
        }
```

Checked in MS SQL - Primary key and identity increment for Id column is configured.

Comment: Do you use fluent api for set Id primary key autoincrement?

Comment: @Den No. I think EF Core did it automatically. I just open table in MS SQL and ensured that Id column is primary key with identity increment enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this attribut to your Model. You need to set up this in your model if you using Code first approach

```
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id { get; set; }
```